Running PySpark script on EMR 6.13.0
I am running a pyspark script on EMR version 6.13.0 and have installed neccessary packages using bootstrap as below:
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas PyDictionary numpy nltk boto3 
sudo python3 -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all
sudo python3 -m venv -d /usr/bin/virtualenv all
sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow venv-pack

I keep running into an error related to Virtualenv,
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run command: /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 --no-pip --system-site-packages virtualenv_application_


Can you please confirm, You are trying to run a python code using virtual environment here and not pyspark code right?

@ArudSekaBerneS I have a PySpark script that imports a Python script (.py), into which I pass the PySpark dataframe for classification purposes. I am encountering the above error while running the python script. I did try to set the python path in pyspark config as below. from pyspark import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON", "/path/to/python/executable")
but still ran into same error Failed to run command: /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 --no-pip --system-site-packages

you had asked the same question couple of days back.

@samkart The other question was specific to ec2 instances (which is closed) and this is regarding EMR issue.
